# Apache Ofbiz installation trouble

Tags: java, apache, ant, ofbiz

I have been trying to install Apache Ofbiz on my 32-bit processor computer, with Windows 7 as the operating system.  I have downloaded Java\jdk1.8.0_25: and apache-ant-1.9.4: and :apache-ofbiz-13.07.01.  I made two environmental variables, JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME; in addition, I included both Java and Ant Apache Bin addresses respectively into the environmental the PATH variable.  Then I ran the CMD and entered the Ofbiz directory' cd [apache ofbiz address], thenceforward, I resumed into entering the the 'ant run-install' command, followed by 'ant run-install-seed', I received a 'build successful' message for both of the commands I entered.  After the foregone commands were executed I proceeded into clicking the startofbiz located inside the apache ofbiz folder.  A cmd screen opened listing all sorts of commands.  Once all these were carried out I typed the following address into my internet search bar:

```
https://localhost:8443/webtools
```

Notwithstanding, I constantly received the following error message that says **THE TEMPLATE LOCATION IS EMPTY** even after a numberless amount of permutations, deleting java, re-installing Ant Apache, etc:

:ERROR MESSAGE:
org.ofbiz.widget.screen.ScreenRenderException: Error rendering screen [component://common/widget/CommonScreens.xml#GlobalDecorator]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template location is empty (Template location is empty)

I have not been able to come to grasps with this issue.  I don't believe things should be this difficult to install.  I stand ready for any guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to your Application setup. it seems your Application setup is fine. This is related to Seed data. The data which requires to initialize the default theme. To load the theme data, execute the following ant command then strat the application. The error should be disappeared now.

```
   ant load-seed
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my best knowledge " **ant load-seed** (Load ONLY the seed data (not seed-initial, demo, ext* or anything else); meant for use after an ualong with the code and needs to be in sync for operation)"

You need to fire **ant load-demo start** (if you're using OFbiz version 13.07.01).Please make your're at the root of the OFbiz project location. Fyi - At very first time it takes more than 20 mins to load all your demo data and seed data, so please be patient. Hope this will help you.

Note: Please rate this if find useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since OFBiz switched from ant to gradle recently, the correct command to load the seed data is as follows (run in root ofbiz folder e.g. /opt/ofbiz and don't forget the quotes):

```
./gradlew "ofbiz --load-data readers=seed"
```

To get the available options for the ofbiz build, run:

```
./gradlew "ofbiz --help"
```

Other ant-to-gradle hints can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/From+Ant+to+Gradle+-+R16.11+version).

You will then need to create an initial user (admin/ofbiz does only exist in demo data).

```
./gradlew loadAdminUserLogin -PuserLoginId=MyUserName
```